# COALESCE in Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using MongoId with ruby on rails. For my search I am using elasticsearch.

I have a date field. It is optional field and I use it as a stop date. In my search I would like to know if my stop date is greater than the search stop date. Example

```
{
  "range": {
    "stop_date": {
      "gt": "#{search_stop}"
    }
  }
}
```

The issue when the stop date is null I need it to be returned in this query, but it is not as the stop date is null or not in the document.

I need when the stop date is null or not in the document the search to be set as a default value like 21/31/2100.

Any advice will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

1. One is to use null_value to stop_date in the mapping. This way ,
   when you are indexing , if stop_date field is missing , the value
   set as null_value will go to the lucene reverse index. But the issue
   with this approach is that , this value would be static across all
   documents and acorss all times. Null_value -
   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html
2. Second approach would be to change the query

   ```
   {
     "query": {
       "filtered": {
         "filter": {
           "or": [
             {
               "range": {
                 "stop_date": {
                   "gt": "#{search_stop}"
                 }
               }
             },
             {
               "missing": {
                 "field": "stop_date"
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Here a document is matched if the stop_date field is missing or when
   the date range filter matched.

My recommendation would be to use second one.

Comment: Thank you so much..I totally agree with you. I tried before the null_value but I did not like it too. I implemented solution 2 :)

Comment: I have one more question about null_value, if there is no tag for the field or null, it should be returned to the default. Or it is only returned the default value only in case the null value not the no tag?